# Problem getting pods stats from kubelet and cri-o

Tags: kubernetes, centos7, kubelet, cri-o

We are running Kubernetes with the following configuration:
On-premise Kubernetes 1.11.3, cri-o 1.11.6 and CentOS7 with UEK-4.14.35

I can't make *crictl stats* to return pods information, it returns empty list only. Has anyone run into the same problem?

Another issue we have, is that when I query the kubelet for stats/summary it returns an empty pods list.

I think that these two issues are related, although I am not sure which one of them is the problem.

Comment: can you run pods? just an issue with stats?

Comment: Yes all is running well, it's just the stats, and a long with the kubelet means that HPA doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked `crictl info` and verify `CRI plugin` runtime status? How did you retrieve stats/summary from `kubelet`?

Comment: Yes, all is running in terms of cri-o pods are starting and terminating, happy campers. For the kubelet, I run, curl localhost:10255/stats/summary and the pods list is an empty array. The kubelet does provide general statistics, but not for pods

Comment: # crictl info
{
  "status": {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "RuntimeReady",
        "status": true,
        "reason": "",
        "message": ""
      },
      {
        "type": "NetworkReady",
        "status": true,
        "reason": "",
        "message": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking `kubelet` service to verify health status and debug any suspicious events within the cluster. I assume that [CRI-O](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-o) runtime engine can select `kubelet` as the main Pods information provider because of its managing Pod lifecycle role.

```
systemctl status kubelet -l

journalctl -u kubelet
```

In case you found some errors or dubious events, share it in a comment below this answer.

However, you can use [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server), which will collect Pod metrics in the cluster and enable `kube-apiserver` flags for [Aggregation Layer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/configure-aggregation-layer/). Here is a good [article](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-autoscaling-custom-metrics/) about Horizontal Pod Autoscaling and monitoring resources via [Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus).